# Customized search box accepting 2 or more inputs on of them having a sliding feature

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like implement on my own website this kind of search box - http://www.chippmunk.com/.
(under Savings Start Here)

How this works with a sliding horizontal input & 2 other inputs, one of which having a dropdown effect? i would like to know how all these things are combined to search.

Do you know some tutorials for this or could you help me to build?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: It's a form with multiple input fields. The logic on how to use these fields is up to you.

Comment: Thanks Vlad Preda! Can you tell me how do i get that sliding feature and club those functions together ?

Comment: The are various javascript libraries you can use. Customizing them is something you will have to do yourself. Check http://jqueryui.com/download/ and http://filamentgroup.com/lab/jquery_ui_selectmenu_an_aria_accessible_plugin_for_styling_a_html_select/

Comment: i have done some changes which i have mentioned below in a answer column.

Answer (score 1):

Based on Vlad Preda's comment, I got a code and edited it slightly to create a slider function which gives me a variable ( say range 23 to 109), which answers part of my question.

```
<div>
      <input id="cost" name="cost" type="range" min=23 max=109 value=93 style="width: 40%;">
      <output for="cost">1</output>
</div>
```

Now I would require to use this as an input, along with another input (an string. e.g. a store name)

How would I manage to combine these two elements to give me a proper search results?

JavaScript code -

```
$(function() {
       var el, newPoint, newPlace, offset;
       $("input[type='range']").change(function() {
         el = $(this);
         width = el.width();
         newPoint = (el.val() - el.attr("min")) / (el.attr("max") - el.attr("min"));
         offset = -1.3;
         if (newPoint < 0) { newPlace = 0;  }
         else if (newPoint > 1) { newPlace = width; }
         else { newPlace = width * newPoint + offset; offset -= newPoint;}
         el
           .next("output")


           .text(el.val());
       })
       .trigger('change');
     });
```

I guess there is a variable e1.val() which has got the updated value, I would need to combine this with another input and pass both parameters to the search variable.