# If condition for multiple search input in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, search

I would like to have a simple if condition for searching multiple inputs (**normal text input**) and from a **dropdown category box**. I need to place a condition as on what basis would the search take place. I need to search either from both inputs on from only one input at a time. If the both are given I need to give one of them more precedence over the other.

```
    <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform"             
     action="http://www.sitename.com/" >

        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"></label>
        <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" align="right"/>

        <label for="category">Select Your Category</label>
        <input class="selectcategorydropdown" type="hidden" id="category"  />

<select name="s" id="category" onchange="getSelectedValue();"> 
    <option value="">none</option> 
    <option value="Kodak Gallery">Kodak Gallery</option>  
    <option value="Ritzpix">Ritxpix</option>  
    <option value="PhotoShelter">PhotoShelter</option> 
    <option value="ScanDigital">ScanDigital</option> 
</select>  

    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="Search" align="right"/>           
        </form>
```

I have two inputs.

I think I have to do similar to this:

```
    <?php
      if (!empty($_POST['search'])) { //if there is something in search_text
         if (empty($_POST['searchform']))  {
              //search by text
          } else {
              //combined text and category search
          }
      } else  { //if there is nothing in search_text
          if (!empty($_POST['category']))  {
              // search by category
          }  else  {
              // error - no data in either $_POST['search'] or $_POST['category']
          }
      } 
?>
```

Am I doing it right?

Comment: please note: the `name` attribute becomes the index in `POST` request, not `id`. plus, didn't you posted it already? giving a -1 for not follow up on the same old question and opening a new one.

Comment: [**1st duplicate**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18712609/conditional-check-for-search-results). [**2nd duplicate**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18650774/assigning-2-inputs-into-a-search-form).[**3rd duplicate**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18634172/customized-search-box-accepting-2-or-more-inputs-on-of-them-having-a-sliding-fea)....

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

   // Check if form was submitted
   if(!isset($_POST['search'])
   {
      // Display the form
   }
   else
   {
      // Form was submitted, check if values are empty
      if(trim($_POST['category1'])=="" )
      {
         // One or more value is empty, do something
      }

      else if (trim($_POST['category2'])=="")
      {
         // Process form
      }
   }

?>
```

Comment: can you please explain me every step, i am just a beginner. i have kept same name attribute in both the inputs i.e. "s". and if i change it, the search url "?s=" changes with it

Comment: Can refer to @itachi answer..3 duplicate and all asked by you i guess..Just have a look at them ..may be you get your answer..

Comment: but changing the name attribute changes the baseline of the search url ... i am trying to implement this on a wordpress site, and i am using the basic wordpress search code. its just that i am not able to combine and build a condition. Right now when i search for a keyword say blog and a select a dropdown menu say movie. the search url is coming as www.sitename.com/?s=movie&s=blog and all the search results are related to blog.